# "Housewife" vs. "homemaker"

Tags: word-choice, differences, word-usage

What is the difference between a **housewife** and a **homemaker**? When can we use *housewife*, and when can we use *homemaker*?

> - I am a housewife.
> - I am a homemaker.

Which of the above examples is correct for a married woman who is unemployed. She is filing out a registration form, applying for a ration card in India. Which of these options should she write under 'Occupation'?

Comment: Tons of good discussions here https://www.google.com/search?q=housewife+vs+homemaker - a homemaker can be man or woman

Comment: This is OT. It asks "Which is correct?" and, in this instance, that is no more than a matter of opinion.

Comment: Depends on where you happen to be, who you are addressing and if it is a formal or informal context. In some contexts they are synonymous.

Comment: I think you need advice as to what terminology is normally used in India. This is a 'cultural' question, not specifically an English Language question. Am voting to leave closed.

Comment: Why do you think one and only one of those is “correct”? What about zero or two of them? And what does “correct” mean, anyway?

Comment: Voting to re-open. A dictionary can tell you what a housewife means, and what a homemaker mean. Which won't help much, because they mean pretty much the same thing. However, they probably won't indicate what's the difference between the two, or why some people avoid the term "housewife". You'd have to know about how English has changed over time to be able to answer that.

Comment: @mplungjan if I do that google search, I get this question as the first hit. As must many other people - the question has been viewed 29860 times.

Comment: This is a year and a half on. What is your point, @AndrewGrimm?

Answer (score 11):

A dictionary will tell you that they mean broadly the same thing:

> [**housewife**](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/housewife?q=housewife) *noun* (plural **housewives**)
>   **1a** married woman whose main occupation is caring for her family, managing household affairs, and doing housework:
>   *the traditional division of labour between the husband as breadwinner and wife as housewife*
>   *I am not just a housewife, I am an accountant, nurse, negotiator, cook, driver*
>
> [**homemaker**](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/homemaker?q=homemaker) *noun*
>   *chiefly North American*
>   a person, especially a woman, who manages a home.
>
> [ODO]

There might be a difference in emphasis. The word *housewife* focuses on the state of the woman [it must be a woman!] as a wife. There may be a slighty pejorative notion (cf [*fishwife*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fishwife?q=fishwife)). Homemaker is a more modern word — OED attests it from 1861 rather than the thirteenth century for *housewife* — and it focuses on creating a **home** rather than simply being in a house. And it's sex-agnostic.

However, which is used is entirely a matter of style and choice, perhaps with a regional bias.

Comment: And looking at the discussions on the web, it seems that being a housewife implicates much more than making the home comfortable for the spouse as is implicated in homemaker.

Comment: Slightly off topic I take it, but it does perhaps speak minor volumes that the word ‘hussy’ originated as simply a contracted, sloppy pronunciation of ‘housewife’.

Comment: Dictionaries take years, if not decades, to catch up.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the apparent differences between  the two (given by dictionaries), you may consider other (off the beaten track) differences also:
 A homemaker enjoys doing his/her work; housewife hates it! (Not for all though.)
Also, a homemaker may not be a wife. Some people can even be home builders!

Comment: Well I haven't yet considered that :). And glad to see that my thoughts matched with the Indian norms.